# Making Large Title Display on iOS 11 Right to Left

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, right-to-left, uinavigationitem, ios11

As of iOS 11, Apple has added Large Title Display Mode for `UINavigationBar` and `UINavigationItem` which makes an effect like this:

[image]

We could simply turn this effect on using the following Swift code:

```
navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

My question is how we can make the large title right to left to be usable for Eastern right to left languages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will happen based on the device language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use this approach :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews[1].semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it should be auto RTL for all RTL languages. All you have to do is to set a device language as one of RTL languages. Or, if you debug this in simulator, you can use on of Instruments Xcode is delivered with to simulate RTL while you are actually using LTR language

Comment: A language like Persian which I am writing for does not exist in device languages and all Iranians set their language to English so I should turn RTL on manually for views. I was asking if there is a way to manually tweak that.

Comment: I suppose you should not RTL for English. And moreover, Persian is present in iOS. In Language and region, when you add a language for a device, type in search farsi and you'll notice Persian.

Comment: In Iran, unfortunately almost nobody uses Persian as the device language for iOS. And that is the problem which all popular apps here has customized their UI manually.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, all apps are in english but RTL?

Comment: They use Persian but their main layout is an English layout manually customized to be RTL.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid, it conflicts with Apple guidelines.
But, since you asking, if you want such a behaviour and if you create layout from code, you can create a function that anchors views and inside of it detect a region/language and then just swap left/right or leading/trailing anchors.